# Can't get a list of streets to create a card

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

```php
 public function create()
    {
       $streets = street::get();
       return view('dashboard.house.created');
    }

 public function store(Request $request)
    {
$this->validate($request, [
            'home_number' => 'required',
            'passport' => 'required',
            'option_1' => 'required',
            'street_id' => 'required',
            'option_2' => 'required',
            'option_3' => 'required',
            'garage' => 'required',
            'apartments' => 'required',
            's_full' => 'required',
            's_life' => 'required',
            's_nlife' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
            'year_create' => 'required',
        ]);

        $homes = Houses::query()->create([
                'home_number' => $request->get('home_number'),
                'passport' => $request->get('passport'),
                'option_1' => $request->get('option_1'),
                'option_2' => $request->get('option_2'),
                'street_id' => $request->get('street_id'),
                'option_3' => $request->get('option_3'),
                'garage' => $request->get('garage'),
                'apartments' => $request->get('apartments'),
                's_full' => $request->get('s_full'),
                's_life' => $request->get('s_life'),
                's_nlife' => $request->get('s_nlife'),
                'status' => $request->get('status'),
                'year_create' => $request->get('year_create'),
            ]
        );
        if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()) {
            $homes->addMediaFromRequest('image')->toMediaCollection('images');
        }
```

I can't fill out the card at home when creating. The list of streets appears, but when you select a street, and further fill in all the fields, the page is simply refreshed without entering the data into the database. Where I made a mistake in the code, please tell me!

UPD:
Now I can not go to the page in the admin panel with a list of houses, writes

```php
ErrorException
Attempt to read property "name" on null (View: D:\laravel-tested\project1\resources\views\Dashboard\house\main.blade.php)
```

The error is highlighted on this line (this is where you get the street and house number).

```php
<td class="w-2/3 py-5">{{$home->street->name}}, {{$home->home_number}}</td>
```

created.blade.php

```php
 <div>
                        <label for="street">Street</label>
                        <select name="street_id" class="w-full">
                            <option selected>Choose street</option>
                            @foreach($streets as $street)
                                <option value="{{$street->id}}">{{$street->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Comment: how did you define the relation between Home and Street ? add it to your question.

Comment: `return $this->hasMany(Houses::class);` in Street Model. @N69S

Comment: Then the error is caused by an erronated street_id. did you setup in place some foreign key or do you have in place a soft delete on the street model ?

Comment: @N69S, I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean, I'm just learning programming

Comment: use my answer, it will explain everything when you test it.

Comment: `'street_id" => 'required',` has a faulty quote

Comment: `'street_id' => $request->get('street_id),` is missing a quote

Comment: Please, share your complete controller, and view if you can, else, we are guessing more than helping you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate the street in your store method, i'm assuming the table in the database is called `streets` and has a primary key `id`

```php
$this->validate($request, [
            'home_number' => 'required',
            //...
            'street_id" => 'exists:streets,id',
            //...
            'year_create' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Maybe `street_id` is not present in the attribute `$fillable` of your House model and it's not set to `'*'`.
Change the way you save the model

```
$homes = new Houses();
$home->home_number = $request->get('home_number');
$home->passport = $request->get('passport');
$home->option_1 = $request->get('option_1');
$home->option_2 = $request->get('option_2');
$home->street_id = $request->get('street_id');
$home->option_3 = $request->get('option_3');
$home->garage = $request->get('garage');
$home->apartments = $request->get('apartments');
$home->s_full = $request->get('s_full');
$home->s_life = $request->get('s_life');
$home->s_nlife = $request->get('s_nlife');
$home->status = $request->get('status');
$home->year_create = $request->get('year_create');
$home->save();

if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()) {
    $homes->addMediaFromRequest('image')->toMediaCollection('images'); 
}
```

or set in Houses class

```
protected $fillable = ['*'];
```

Comment: It just refreshes the page and removes the filled fields. I pointed : `'street_id" => 'exists:street,id',`

Comment: Wrong quote here too `'street_id"`

Comment: @brombeer, I saw an error, for some reason it was deleted when copying. In the document itself, everything is correctly set

Comment: @N69S, Fields are updated, data is entered into the database, but the street is not entered into the database

Comment: @N69S, yyep. The field is not filled

Comment: @YuraLons the error you saw was the validator ? so the input street_id is not sent in your request ? can you add the form to your question ?

Comment: @N69S, There are no mistakes. It just does not redirect to a page with a list of all streets as shown at the end of the route function

Comment: @YuraLons Remove the redirect and post the error you are getting. We dont have enough info to help you

Comment: @N69S, Route also had nothing to do with it. There are no errors.

Comment: @N69S, All fields are filled in, but the street field is not. Maybe I am not passing some parameter correctly in the view?

Comment: @N69S, i update my code. Add created.blade.php

Comment: @YuraLons check the edit. if it doesnt work then start `dd()` everything and make the question clearer

Comment: @N69S, It's work.Only the problem with the redirection remains. How to return me after filling in the fields on the page with the list of houses? Since a simple route does not work